# calling parent's function on iframe onload?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

how to call parent's function from a newly dynamically created iframe?

```
function PARENTS_TEST() {
}

function on_something_clicked() {
  $('#somediv').html("<iframe src='somehtml.html' ONLOAD?='PARENTS_TEST()'></iframe>");
}
```

when i don't want to modify somehtml.html at all..

Answer (score 1):

try this code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
function game()
{
alert("hiii");
}
function pfun()
{
$("#div1").html('<iframe id="if1" src="www.google.com" onload="game();">');


}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="pfun();">
<div id="div1">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
function PARENTS_TEST() {
}

function on_something_clicked() {
  $('#somediv').html("<iframe src='somehtml.html' ONLOAD?='parent.PARENTS_TEST()'></iframe>");
```